# Difference between steady and moving electrons

Tags: electromagnetism

Recently I am reading about the elecctromagnetism. When the electrons are at rest, they produce electric field and when in motion they produce magnetic field. Why so?

What happens to a electron when it get velocity? Isn't the total thing is relative ? We can choose a reference frame to make their relative velocity zero. Will then the magnetic field produced by them be zero?

Moreover I want to know "what happens to an electron when it get speed?"

Comment: This is not what I want. I just want to know that, what happens to an electron when it get speed. In static condition it produce electric field but v in moving condition it produce a completely different type of force field. However they both obey inverted square law, but their vectorial properties are different. How this strange things are produced by only a "moving" 'charge'.

Answer (score 1):

If there were just one particle it might be possible not pick a frame where it is or was at rest and hope to get a purely magnetic fields.

However, if it accelerates it also produces an electromagnetic field but even if it doesn't there can be a problem.

Namely, what if there were multiple charges moving at different speeds (this is common) then there is no frame where they are all at rest. So you have to deal with moving charges because in general it is unavoidable.

What really happens is the electric and magnetic fields adjust themselves based on each other and based on the charges and currents.

Comment: This is a better explanation as to say that a moving charged particle has not an electric field only but a magnetic field too. The magnetic field does not came from nothing, it is always an interaction with other fields, the magnetic field is induced.

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to distinguish between electric field and magnetic field. Electron is able to produce a field which shows different behavior according to its conditions.

Comment: How can you describe the phenomena, 'two conducting wires repeals each other with a linear static charge density, but attracts when the current is flowing.'